# Default Language on deployment IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have two different servers, where I need to deploy an application.
Both are almost identical. The only thing that differs is one update.

The problem is the following: On deployment one of the servers raises a compile error(At the end of the question. It is too big)

I noticed this: `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe`
So I checked the IIS settings and yes, there it was. The `Default Language under the .NET Compilation` menu was set to `vb`.

It is weird because the other server has exactly the same settings, also this one, but somehow it manages to switch to `css.exe` and compile the web application.

Any idea why these two servers behave different with the same application?
Are there any settings to set this default language in Visual studio?

**Web Application Type**

ASP .Net WebForms 4.5.1

**Server Config**

Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

IIS 8.5.9600.16384

**Web.config**

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5.1">
```

**Update missing in the "error" server**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2992080

**Compile error**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error 
>     Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741511.
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> ﻿c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\c2f80fba\ecba2d49_396ed101\LORT.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\3dfdc744\053bcce7_ab7dd001\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\1ae92062\f5331ae8_ab7dd001\AspNet.ScriptManager.bootstrap.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\d5f86421\4f38f3c6_d57ed001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\4e6cc1e7\e54a63e8_ab7dd001\AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\b2a0cd7a\b55fc9e8_ab7dd001\Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\2698ec6c\a58222e6_ab7dd001\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\b6c06e10\284bd7c6_d57ed001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\04c0eb7e\d5db7ae6_ab7dd001\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\9a1d29b5\2151e7c6_d57ed001\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\430e4b69\7d639bc7_d57ed001\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\9f8e94f4\e5feb6ea_ab7dd001\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\ac2ec17e\556dede9_ab7dd001\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\366482ea\55c51ae7_ab7dd001\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\52c841ec\e58568e9_ab7dd001\Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\b3447c74\ee73ab85_396ed101\App_global.asax.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\cc2bf574\952fc8c6_d57ed001\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\9e52f2ee\1f3b65c5_d57ed001\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\assembly\dl3\54bc6c65\d52527eb_ab7dd001\Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\App_Theme_DesignLH.pumitven.dll" /debug- /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\"Web\" /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Collections.Specialized,System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,System.Configuration,System.Linq,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.Caching,System.Web.DynamicData,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls,System.Xml.Linq,System.Web.Optimization,LORT /warnaserror- /optionInfer+  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\App_Theme_DesignLH.pumitven.0.vb" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a4cfed00\726e4389\App_Theme_DesignLH.pumitven.1.vb"
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

Comment: Have you try **aspnet_regiis /iru** to reinstall the .Net Framework ?

Comment: @D4rkTiger no, I didn't try. Actually it works if I set the default language manually, so my first attempts are in the direction of finding "hidden" settings.

Comment: What is the value you've set manually in default language to do your application worked ?

Comment: @D4rkTiger C#. By default appears vb. The web app works in the other server also with the default set to vb.

Comment: So, in your web.config you have a difference between servers. One has defaultlanguage defined on 'vb' vs nothing specified in the other web.config. That is very strange. Are you sure you have the same version of .Net Framework installed ?

Comment: @D4rkTiger No. Both servers and both web.config have the same settings and are identical but the `Server name` . That's the problem. In both servers the default language is set to `vb` but only one o the servers run the web application without problem. The other one shows the compile error I wrote.

Comment: Try by redo the issue and see in EventViewer into the Application log part to have more details